# TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer (find and replace)

Tags: python-3.x

I keep getting a type error in Python and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I want to replace '100' in the url to whatever integer the user types into the input. Thanks for you help!

```
import urllib.request
num=str(input("Numerical Currency Amount to Convert: "))
url = 'https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=100&from=USD&to=EUR'
url_adjusted = url.replace(url,'100',num)
```

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: you use num=str(), and then want to replace '100' with num but num is a str and not an int

Comment: @Pizzalord not really... the problem is he is supplying num as integer parameter of "how often" something should be replaces - and the whole syntax is wrong.

Comment: @PatrickArtner my bad  i have not worked with python for a while

Answer (score 0):

You are using replace wrong:

```
import urllib.request
num=str(input("Numerical Currency Amount to Convert: "))
url = 'https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=100&from=USD&to=EUR'
url_adjusted = url.replace('100',num,1)
```

works. See https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

You do not need to supply, `url` is the string thats looked into , `100` should be replaced by `num` and that exactly 1 times.

Answer (score 0):

in your case [replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) in python should only take two arguement so change `url.replace(url,'100',num)` to `url.replace('100',num)`. this will hopefuly solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the str.replace in the wrong way. You can read more on this function [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm).

Your code should be:

```
url_adjusted = url.replace('100',num)
```

The third parameter is used for how many times you want to replace `'100'` with `num`. If it is only once then do:

```
url_adjusted = url.replace('100',num,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code in line:
url_adjusted = url.replace(url,'100',num)

to:
url_adjusted = url.replace('100',num)